# Qt Creator - how to open the property editor

Tags: qt-creator, property-editor

whenever I opened a cpp file I can only see the editor, I can't see the property edior.

When I tried to see it by going through

Tools->Form Editor->views

Every thing is disabled. So I cant click anything there.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try openning a ui file or creating a "Qt Designer Form" and it should be enabled there, it's the one in the lower right corner.

The property editor is part of the Qt Designer, which is a WYSIWYG tool (integrated with Qt Creator) for creating user interfaces. It's a two columns table that lets you edit in a quick and easy way the properties of the Qt widgets like: the text that shows, geometry or tooltip. This properties depends on the selected widget.

This answer is based on the assumption that you tried to use the Qt Creator with the wrong type of file. If you still don't see the property editor when working with a Designer form (ui file) then your Qt Creator installation is having a problem and I don't know what to do then :S.

Comment: My main problem is when ever I open a c++ file, I can't compile . Because everything is disabled.

Comment: Have you tried opening a project? The compile function is only available for projects and not form single files.

Why don't you Take a look to the Qt Creator Manual at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-1.3/index.html ?

Comment: You are exactly correct, I nearly figured out this, few days before.
And so many thanks for the link provided